# Database design with one giant polymorphic table

Tags: mysql, schema, rdbms

I have a MySQL database with many different types that need a lot of the same things. For example, we have tables for `reservations`, `customers`, and `accounts`, and each of these needs EAV-type properties and a set of permission configurations.

My question is: Should I make the EAV and permission implementations polymorphic? So, each reservation, customer, and account gets an `entity_id` and `entity_type_id` that can be inserted to the `| entity_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | value |` table? There would then be an `entities` table with `| id | entity_type_id |` that would need to be inserted whenever a new reservation, customer, or account were created.

Or should I have `reservation_eav`, `customer_eav`, `accounts_eav` tables? We will always know the entity type that we are looking for, so there's no need to return multiple types of entities in a single query. We will, however, need to grab multiple entities of the same type in several cases.

My reason for multiple tables is strictly performance. There's going to be a ton of reservations, not nearly as many accounts, and customers are somewhere in between. Part of me thinks this huge set of reservations will slow down lookups for accounts' / customers' AVs. However, I don't know if the performance advantages will be significant with proper indexing, and I do feel like the single, polymorphic table would make the schema simpler.

Comment: Why do they need EAVs?

Comment: We put a lot of thought into the decision trying to avoid EAV if at all possible, but the companies that are using this system have requirements that are far too different regarding the data they want to collect, so we need some type of dynamic schema. We have already developed the meta tables for attribute information / validation / etc.

Comment: Each of these tables: `reservations`, `customers`, `accounts`, are entities that are owned by `companies`, and each company wants to be able to create arbitrary properties for these things. We've developed a table of `rules` that each has a regexp (dates, emails, cc#, etc), and we allow the company to create attributes that belong to these `rules`.

Comment: ...but the core data within reservations, customers, and accounts is available (or potentially available) to all of your clients.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand. Of course, we have attributes that always apply to these types, and those are columns in the corresponding tables. The problem is that `companies` want to also define additional properties that they can use to describe each of these types. They only need to be editable and searchable, so we are not basing any program logic on them. For example, one company may want to know the hair color of their customers, another company may not care about that.

Comment: Sorry, that was a question: Is the core data within reservations, customers, and accounts available to all of your clients? Or does each client have their own version of the database, with their own core data?

Comment: Yes, each client has their own database so to speak, for each entity type. So if company A wants to record that customer A has brown hair, company B should not see that information for customer A. Furthermore, company B should be able to define their own version of Hair Color, and say that customer A has light brown hair.